# Unity: Build on specific wall of the box

Tags: c#, unity

I'm trying to program game similar to Minecraft - you build environment from cubes. So far I found that Unity has a function which tells if mouse is over a box collider. I need a function which will tell me if my mouse is touching specific wall of the cube - to be able to add a cube from side of this wall. I was thinking about many solutions - most obvious is to make a new cube from six different walls which own collider for each one - for me it sounds like a little overkill. I could also try to get it from position of mouse, camera and center of a box... but it sounds like even bigger overkill.

How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the normal from the collision point of a raycast**

Ensure that your world is axis aligned for this to work properly.

Cast [a ray from your camera](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CameraRays.html) to your mouse into the scene. When it collides with a box collider, utilize the [normal](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-normal.html) property of the [RayCastHit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) object to determine which side of the cube was hit.

The normal will tell you which direction to move away from your existing cube to place the new cube.

Comment: With Unity the same raycast that gets you a hit point also tells you the surface normal at that point, which for a cube will already be an axis-aligned unit vector pointing outward from the face, so you don't need to do the position comparison.

Comment: Ah, nice, I'll update.